What is the exact size of the default marker in Maps SDK for Android?
I would like to know the default dimensions of the marker that is used by the Maps SDK. I have only found information about the maximum dimensions (64x64 px), but I couldn’t find a definitive answer anywhere. But if there is no such value, what dimensions should I use for custom marker in bmp format?
I’ve searched both through the documentation and here.

There is no "official default size", a marker can be any size you want plus the maps api probably has different sizes for different screen densities
